# How to define css custom property

Tags: css-variables

I defined a custom css variable/property for say, border-color, text-color etc. in my main stylesheet at root element. Then used them in respective places in subsequent stylesheet. The browser on rendering shows the color I defined but when I inspect the element property where I used the custom property (via say chrome's devtool by taking mouse pointer over that property/variable, it says  not defined).
I am unable to understand. Can some one help me out at it.

```
/* my main style sheet */
:root{--myColor:red;}

/* secondary style sheet case 1*/
border-color-top: var(--myColor); 
/* here mouse pointer over property in devtools says *--myColor is not defined* yet the border renders red color;*/
```

Comment: How are you looking at the property? It does show up under styles for me (at least if I correct your typo), but the "Properties" tab in the Inspector shows only _JavaScript_ properties, not styles.

Comment: Right click on element (in chrome), select Inspect, then on the right hand side in the styles Tab.

Comment: Yes, then I see this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUQD8.png

Comment: https://snipboard.io/7aVxf2.jpg
but its taking the color defined in master css file...
And yes sorry for late reply...

Comment: You should provide your actual source. This is not enough to go on.